# Error in installing the FIELDimageR package in R

Tags: r, r-package

I am trying to install an R package called "FIELDimageR". I have gone through few literature and followed many steps but didn't resolve the issue. I am using RStudio with R version 3.6.1, Through the conventional method of installing any package, its saying the FIELDimageR is not available for R version 3.6.1

Here are the steps, I have followed

## Installed Rtools35 (as compatible with R3.6.1)

```
library(devtools)
install_github("filipematias23/FIELDimageR")
```

## error

```
Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
  Timeout was reached: [api.github.com] Operation timed out after 10001 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

## alternatively

```
library(remotes)
remotes::install_github("filipematias23/FIELDimageR")
```

## error

```
Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
  Timeout was reached: [api.github.com] Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

## if through conventional way

```
install.packages("FIELDimageR")
```

## error

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘FIELDimageR’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This has been addressed and resolved by Filipe

https://community.opendronemap.org/t/about-the-fieldimager-category/4130/8?u=amithaldar87